# Android - Include layout from another module

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a module called **TestGUILib** and I have specified **testview.xml** with a simple FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing View!" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I tried to use this layout in my main app **activity_main**. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sam.testapp1.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/testview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Everything works fine. It compiles ok and runs ok. But the preview doesn't work. It shows the blank screen (ie. when I clicked on "Design", it turns blank) with render errors:

> Could not find layout resource matching value 0x7F04002F (resolved name: testview) in current configuration.

Also, there is a line under **testview** (ie. include layout="@layout/**testview**"). When I rolled my mouse over, it said

> Typo in the word 'testview'
>
> Spellchecker inspection helps locate typos and misspelling in your code, comments and literals, and fix them in one click.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go to "File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...", click "Invalidate and Restart". it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have `moduleOne` and `moduleTwo` and if you want to use moduleTwo resources in moduleOne add following (sample) code **in moduleOne gradle**

```
    dependencies {
    compile project(':moduleTwo')
   }
```

*This will include moduleOne into you moduleTwo* in order to *use its resouces* including layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Possible you have forgotten to enable

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

in the second module. In that case viewbinding will not find view and show it red like an unknown element